# How to create beepvar or dayvar from time-varying VAR

Tags: r, time-series, var, mixed-models

For my Thesis, I am applying time-varying vector autoregression (TVVAR) on time-series objects. I am using a dataset from an open-source paper. As R-package I am using the MGM package which allows processing of mixed graphical models and tv-vars.

To my problem: I want to apply a TVVAR on a dataset which should predict behaviour. I want to predict two variables "I feel stressed" on "depressed/down". However, my R skills aren't that fully developed and to correctly implement all parameters of the TVVAR function I need to create two objects:

- Beepvar (which is like the number of observations on a day)
- Dayvar (the number of days)

I want to create these beepvar and dayvar objects within R, but I don't really know how to subset them from the dataset

Here is a picture of the datasets variables I want to subset.[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzchv.png)

multiple observations on one day (e.g. 2/6/2018 is beepvar) I want to create and object that repeats itself per day so to say on 2/6/2018 I have 6 beeps and on 2/7/2018 I have 8 beeps and 2/8/2018 I have only 3 because of NA's or so.

2nd: I also want to create a dayvar object which repeats the days to say, 2/6/2018, 2/7/2018 and so on

EDIT** here is a part of my dataset:

```
    structure(list(`Survey Creation Date` = c("2/6/2018 14:33", "2/6/2018 16:20", 
"2/6/2018 18:54", "2/6/2018 20:08", "2/6/2018 22:29", "2/7/2018 8:43", 
"2/7/2018 10:52", "2/7/2018 12:21", "2/7/2018 14:56", "2/7/2018 16:20"
), `Survey Completion Date` = c("2/6/2018 14:56", "2/6/2018 16:22", 
"2/6/2018 18:58", "2/6/2018 20:22", "2/6/2018 22:46", "2/7/2018 8:44", 
"2/7/2018 11:23", "2/7/2018 12:26", "2/7/2018 14:58", "2/7/2018 16:21"
), `Since your last survey; how many alcoholic drinks have you had?` = c(0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `I feel comfortable in my current location` = c(88, 
81, 88, 89, 95, 94, 62, 82, 63, 80), `I feel stressed` = c(10, 
12, 69, 34, 16, 6, 27, 35, 56, 28), `I feel down/depressed` = c(14, 
18, 15, 18, 5, 2, 8, 4, 0, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my code in question:

```
tvvar_obj <- tvmvar(data = stress_data,
                type = rep("g", 12),
                level = rep(1, 12), 
                lambdaSel = "CV",
                timepoints = #timepoint object I created, 
                estpoints = seq(0, 1, length = 20), 
                bandwidth = ### need bandwidth,
                lags = 1,
                beepvar = #NUMBER OF OBSERVATIONS ON A DAY,
                dayvar = #DAYS OF OBSERVATION,
                scale = TRUE,
                pbar = TRUE)
```

How do I do this? I am very thankful for every help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We'll need data, so `dput(my_data[1:10, 1:6])` then copy `structure(...)` to here at bottom as Data:

Comment: Hello Chris! Thanks, what do you mean exactly by this? Do you need the dataset I am working on? Or is that code referring to the manipulation I have to do?

Comment: We need 'some of the data' to see if proposed solutions work. The `dput` selects 10 rows and the first 6 columns (couldn't tell how many columns you have), so you could `dput(my_data[1:10, ])`. The resulting `structure(...)` is the beauty part because anyone can copy it and `jada_data <- structure(...)`, and be working with your data. So you copy the whole structure result here instead of the picture.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I edited the question with the `structure(...)` output